# Is there any way to override some released functions in Flink’s /lib folder?

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

My flink applications is deployed by yarn and I include all the necessary flink dependencies in Flink’s /lib folder. Now I want to add some unique features to the jar 'flink-table-planner', but I can not modify the jar in the lib folder directly because it is a common dependence all of my partner used.

I attempt to override it in user code which sumbmitted to yarn in jar. But it would be overrided by the codes in /lib folders.

So, is there any way to implement it? I'd be grateful if you give me some tips!

Comment: For detail, in the transformation generation phase, I want to use my own class implemented by myself instead of in the release jar which have same path and name. Currently I want to replace the class named CommonExecLookupJoin.

Answer (score -1):

I use the configuration 'classloader.parent-first-patterns.default' to override the default value, but it doesn't work, flink still work with the classes in the '/lib' folder rather than mine.

Comment: please elaborate.

Comment: I double that the granularity of the configuration 'classloader.parent-first-patterns.default' is jar rather than class. I‘m not sure.